# PHP Why Else statment strangely doesnt work

Tags: php

I have this following piece of code

```
include_once("config/connection.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM qqqq WHERE LOWER(pdf_ad) LIKE '%" . $aranacak_metin . "%'";
$result = $DBcon->query($sql);

if ($result && is_array($result) && count($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        $yeniad = seo($row['pdf_ad']);
        echo '<form action="/indir/' . $yeniad . '/' . $row['pdf_liste_no'] . '" id="sorgu" method="post">';
        echo '<li class="list-group-item">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $row['pdf_liste_no'] . '">';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $row['pdf_ad'] . '">';
        echo '<img alt="' . $row['pdf_ad'] . '" src="' . $row['pdf_resim'] . '" width=120" height="150"><a style="font-size:20px; text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="#"> ' . $row['pdf_ad'] . '</a>  ';
        echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">';
        echo '<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-lg"></i>';
        echo '</button>';
        echo '</li>';
        echo '</form>';
    }
} else {
    echo $aranacak_metin;
}
```

if statement does its job if the result is set shows the rows but if there is no match in DB else statement 
doesnt work am i missing something need your help thank you

update:it turns else everytime now

Comment: because `$result` is always set.

Comment: You have to check if `$result` is empty or not `(!empty($result))`, `$result` is always set it returns true or false every time,

Comment: i did what you guys say but still i dont get any else message

Comment: @EnginYücelen Can you please post the updated code? With the changes given by Devsi and Robin

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my php version it worked ?

Answer (score 0):

in current scenario `$result` is always set. so just check you got any match record or not, based on that put conditions as below.

```
if($result && $result->num_rows && $result->num_rows > 0){

} else {

}
```

if its PDO query then

```
if($result && is_array($result) && count($result) > 0){

} else {

}
```

Comment: i'm getting error Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$num_rows

Comment: @EnginYücelen Then change it to `($result && isset($result->num_rows) && $result->num_rows > 0)` .

Comment: @EnginYücelen use second one in my answer if u r using PDO.

Comment: Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable i'm having this error but still it doesnt give me the else

Comment: what you have got in $result ?

Comment: just add one more condition is_array() as above answer

Comment: i have been taught that this way and the query should give me names

Comment: it turns else everytime

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
if ( is_array($result) && count($result) > 0 ) {

   // staff

} else {

   echo $aranacak_metin;
}
```